# Is there a standard way to declare your preferred diff tool under Unix/Linux?

Tags: diff, development-environment

I want to know if there is a standardized way to declare your prefer diff tool (as for file or directory comparison).

For preferred editor there is the `EDITOR` environment variable, but I wasn't able to find one for diff.

If not maybe someone wrote a script that can reconfigure most used tools to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`EDITOR` is usually used by various shells that provide line-editing functionality on certain things like your command history. For example, pressing `v` in `vi-edit` mode within `bash` will bring up the command for editing in your preferred editor.

I'm unaware of *any* aspects of the shell that do `diff` processing so the need for a `DIFF` variable seems unnecessary. If you want to `diff` some files, just use `diff` or your preferred one if not `diff`.

However, nothing is stopping you from writing a program of your own which *does* use a `DIFF` variable to perform difference analysis on files.